# Magento 1.9.2.3. Forget Password: Page Reload Loop

Tags: magento, forgot-password

I updated my Magento to 1.9.2.3.
Forgot Password is broken:
1. Click "Forget Password" = OK
2. Receive E-Mail with Link = OK (mymagento.com/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=34&token=9831c0afde798f697058617781bfa375)
3. Type in a new password and click "save" = Problem, the pages just reload and no error, no changed pw.

Anyone else?
I use core-file at base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
Also the my custom customer.xml is updated to the base version with customer_account_changeforgotten

Added also a form-Key which did not help.